# Get-Website command returning multiple websites

Tags: powershell, iis-7

In PowerShell V3, I am having issue with Get-Website command.

Whenever I do

```
PS c:\> Get-Website -Name "MyWebsite"
```

It returns all the websites on that server.  It is either the command is behaving differently or I am getting it wrong.

If I do a Get-type on the returned object then it is of type Array.  If I understand it right then it should only return one website.

Please advise.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170530/powershell-get-website-name-parameter-is-ignored/8772609#8772609

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug with the command [bug link](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/597787/get-website-always-returns-full-list-of-web-sites)

Wrapping the name in wildcard characters works:

```
  get-website -name "*MyWebsite*"
```